# Better way to reconstruct first instance of a possibly-repeated character within a string without using preg_* functions

Tags: php, repeat

A function I am using needs to detect the first instance of a character, and if the character is repetitive, reconstruct the repetitive substring. For example:

```
$x = 'fhdfhbc::::dcdcdcuttr482rdvcjv:ducvdk:::chjvdbj'; // ---> function should extract ::::
```

I do not want to use any of the `preg_*` functions as I avoid these when possible (because these functions are slow). My solution is currently this:

```
$char = ":"; // this would be set as necessary

$char_substring = str_repeat($char, strspn(strstr($x, $char), $char)); // yields ---> ::::
```

Note you cannot use `strrpos` here because there may be (in this case) colons at the other end of the string. You CAN use `explode`, then run a `for` or `foreach` loop, concatenating on the empties, or some variation of this:

```
$explode = explode($char, $x);
$substring = $char; // explode array should have 1 less empty member than the repeated character, so need to start with char count of 1
$emptyEncountered = false;
for($i = 0, $count = count($explode); $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($explode[$i]) {
        if ($emptyEncountered) break;
    } else {
        $emptyEncountered = true;
        $substring .= $char;
    }
}

echo $substring; // ---> ::::
```

**Is there a better way than using preg_*, a for/each loop, or str_repeat(strspn(strstr()))?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper `preg_*` implementation will outperform the `explode` approach of yours hands down, not only in time but also in terms of memory consumption and required allocations.

The only implementation I can think of which is efficient, and which adheres to your constraints, would be a `while` loop:

```
$substring = '';

$i = strpos($haystack, $needle);
do {
    $substring .= $needle;
    ++$i;
}
while (isset($haystack{$i}) && $haystack{$i} === $needle);

return $substring;
```

However, you already have the most efficient implementation yourself:

```
return str_repeat($needle, strspn(strstr($haystack, $needle), $needle));
```

It is nicely functional in nature too.

> Your implementations are missing error handling, so does my `while` implementation. Adding it is definitely required in my opinion but I ignore it because you do.

---

Results on my i7 machine with Win 10 PHP TS x64 7.1:

```
$ bench 10000
0.0040609836578369  # str_repeat
0.0044500827789307  # preg_match
0.0046060085296631  # while
0.0050818920135498  # for
0.0052239894866943  # preg_match + preg_quote
0.0079050064086914  # explode
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

function bench(callable $cb): void {
    global $argv;

    $limit = 1000;
    if (isset($argv[1]) && is_numeric($argv[1])) {
        $limit = (int) $argv[1];
    }
    elseif (isset($_ENV['LOOP']) && is_numeric($_ENV['LOOP'])) {
        $limit = (int) $_ENV['LOOP'];
    }

    gc_collect_cycles();
    gc_disable();
    $start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
        $cb();
    }
    $end = microtime(true);
    gc_enable();
    gc_collect_cycles();

    echo $end - $start, "\n";
}

$haystack = 'fhdfhbc::::dcdcdcuttr482rdvcjv:ducvdk:::chjvdbj';
$needle   = ':';

bench(function () use ($haystack, $needle) {
    return str_repeat($needle, strspn(strstr($haystack, $needle), $needle));
});

bench(function () use ($haystack, $needle) {
    preg_match("/{$needle}{2,}/", $haystack, $matches);

    return $matches[0] ?? '';
});

bench(function () use ($haystack, $needle) {
    $substring = '';
    $i         = strpos($haystack, $needle);

    do {
        $substring .= $needle;
        ++$i;
    }
    while (isset($haystack{$i}) && $haystack{$i} === $needle);

    return $substring;
});

bench(function () use ($haystack, $needle) {
    $substring = '';

    for ($i = strpos($haystack, $needle); isset($haystack{$i}) && $haystack{$i} === $needle; ++$i) {
        $substring .= $needle;
    }

    return $substring;
});

bench(function () use ($haystack, $needle) {
    $needle = preg_quote($needle, '/');

    preg_match("/{$needle}{2,}/", $haystack, $matches);

    return $matches[0] ?? '';
});

bench(function () use ($haystack, $needle) {
    $explode   = explode($needle, $haystack);
    $substring = $needle;
    $empty     = false;

    for ($i = 0, $count = count($explode); $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($explode[$i]) {
            if ($empty) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            $empty     = true;
            $substring .= $needle;
        }
    }

    return $substring;
});
```